# Tablesorter - How to ignore sort for certain cell value?

Tags: tablesorter

How can I prevent Tablesorter from sorting a certain value or keep these values at the bottom? More specifically, this certain value will always be a **-**

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bach</td>
      <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to keep Doe with the value "-" always at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Tablesorter has an [`emptyTo` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#emptyto) which can modify the sort behavior of empty, or non-numeric, cells ([demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-sort-empty.html))

In this case, you might need to set a `data-text` attribute (modified by the [`textAttribute` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textattribute) to an empty string.

HTML

```
<td data-text="">-</td>
```

JS

```
$('#myTable').tablesorter({
  // ...
  emptyTo: 'bottom'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The <td> will be dynamically generated so we won't know which <td> will be <td>-</td>.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Doc: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-digits-strings.html

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
    stringTo: 'bottom'
  });
});
```